# P & T Matrix URL Title [current] & EE 2.7.2 fatal error

Tags: matrix

Have been unable to clear this / or uninstall.  Can't open FT in addons dropdown in CP

Fatal error: Class Matrix_url_title_ft contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (EE_Fieldtype::display_field) in /var/www/www.domain/system/expressionengine/third_party/matrix_url_title/ft.matrix_url_title.php on line 166

https://github.com/pixelandtonic/matrix_url_title

Help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit line 11 of **/expressionengine/third_party/matrix_url_title/ft.matrix_url_title.php** to start with

```
abstract class Matrix_url_title_ft
```

Just add the word `abstract`.